# Como remover eventos do FullCalendar?

Tags: php, javascript, fullcalendar

Estou usando isso:

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
},
```

Meu banco de dados tem: `id`, `title`, `start`, `end`, `username` que eu tentei mudar `"event.id"` para `"id"`, mas nada parece funcionar. Quando clico no evento, todos os eventos são removidos do calendário, mas não do banco de dados. Se eu atualizar a página eles aparecem novamente.

Comment: Ou não tens aí o código completo, ou então salta à vista um problema: `event` é uma variavel que não existe. Já viste no browser se esse código javascript está a dar erros?

Comment: Ao invés de usar event.id você tem que usar calEvent.id ou mudar o nome 'calEvent' para event
E aliás, para remover apenas um evento você deve usar 'removeEvent' no singular, senão ele exclui todos mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

No caso, vc irá ter que fazer alguma chamada por ajax, por exemplo, para um controlador no seu php, por exemplo:

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'calendario.php',
        data: {'calendario_id' : event.id},
        success: function() {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);

        }
    });
},
```

e com isso no seu calendario.php que irá receber a requisição irá fazer a ação de remover da sua tabela.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link https://www.webslesson.info/2017/12/jquery-fullcalandar-integration-with-php-and-mysql.html