# Fullcalendar remover evento Ajax/PHP

Tags: php, ajax, fullcalendar

Eu estou tentando usar o método removeEvent em meu calendário e enviar dados em ajax para excluir o evento do meu banco de dados.

```
    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'calendar/remove_event.php',
       data: 'id=' + event.id,
       type: "POST",
       success: function () {
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
       }
   });
},
```

e o PHP:

```
    $id = $_POST['id'];

$ligacao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydatabase");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Can't connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "delete from events WHERE id= '$id'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql);
mysqli_close($ligacao);
```

Quando clico no evento, ele é removido do calendário, mas se eu atualizar a página ele está lá novamente, porque ele não foi removido do banco de dados. Aqui está a documentação para estes métodos (removeEvent e eventClick):

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEvents/

A variável id é usada noutros sitios com sucesso por exemplo o eventDrop onde pego no evento e largo em cima de outra data, fazendo o update na base de dados das novas datas para o respetivo evento:

```
eventDrop: function (event, delta) {
                            start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                            end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'calendar/update_events.php',
                                data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&id=' + event.id,
                                type: "POST",
                            });
                        },
```

Comment: Bom amigo essa variavel "event.id" esta indo corretamente ?

Comment: Altere esse trecho no seu código `success: function (data) { console.log(data);` e [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/62565/edit) sua pergunta adicionando o resultado do _console_.

Comment: ainda ontem perguntaste o mesmo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61230/como-remover-eventos-do-fullcalendar porque não continuar nessa pergunta? inclusivamente já te perguntei sobre a existência dessa variavel `event`

Comment: Quando insiro um evento tenho de indicar o title, e o id é inserido automaticamente. A variável está definida corretamente porque a uso noutros métodos como "eventDrop" e "eventResize".

Comment: É ai que está o problema, você está tentando deletar do banco de dados um evento com o id que "não existe" ou provavelmente não é referente a aquele evento, pois é um ID do Fullcalendar e não do seu banco de dados. [Insira por favor na tua pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/62565/edit) o código onde você monta o calendário e os eventos.

Comment: João, marquei esta sua pergunta como duplicata da outra que fez há dois dias porque o seu problema é o mesmo. Como o KaduAmaral já mencionou, para adicionar mais informações sobre seu problema, edite a pergunta original. Abraço!